# How do I iterate over all imported functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I have this code that works well. It works in a way that I have to type a function such as soccer for the games.soccer module to be active then i can type a query such as 'latest scores', again after i close this then type autocare for this to work.. I need help in coding a way to just type the query e.g 'latest scores'..then this will iterate over all imported functions in the PLAY dictionary to find the answer.Here is the code

```
import games
import clauseq11
PLAY = {
    'soccer': games.soccer,
    'nba': games.nba,
    'autorace': games.autorace,
    'search_name': clauseq11.search_name,
    'answer_neg1': clauseq11.answer_neg1,
    }

while True:
    question = input('Please enter your question: ').lower()
    if not question:
        break
    for key, func in PLAY.items():             
        if key in question:
            func()
            break
    else:
        print('Sorry I do not have an answer! :(')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is a way to get a function name from user and execute a function with that name if it exists in a module you have imported. Here is all you need to implement it:

Example module `t.py`:

```
def foo(): print 'foo here!'
def bar(): print 'bar here!'
```

Import the module:

```
In [1]: import t
```

Find out what functions your module has:

```
In [2]: print dir(t)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Execute a function in your module which has a given name:

```
In [3]: getattr(t, 'foo')()
foo here!
```

Comment: thanks! the functions are supposed to answer(print) to an asked query. My headache is to with the same query, to iterate over the functions till the correct one answers

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but you don't have to iterate over the functions, really. You just assume the function is there and try to call it. If it's not there (say, user made a typo), an exception (KeyError) will be thrown, which you have to catch and handle (say, print 'function not found' to the user.

Comment: Thanks, what i meant is when the user types a query, from the many functions imported, the answer should be printed after the iteration through the dictionary of functions